# C# Selenium Unable to locate Button in Modal - not an Iframe

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, modal-dialog

**The Problem:**
I get a "NoSuchElementException:Unable to locate element error".

**The Source Code of my Program which generates the Exception:**
The last line of code generates, the following error:
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#\30 0d43143-fd7b-4e93-89a2-c48370d9a875"}

```
IWebElement DeleteModalPopUpFooter = existingChromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[3]"));
IWebElement DeleteButton = DeleteModalPopUpFooter.FindElement(By.Id("00d43143-fd7b-4e93-89a2-c48370d9a875"));
```

**Question**
How is it, that Selenium can locate the DeleteModalPopUpFooter, first line, but not the button within the footer? I don't understand what I am overlooking

I tried to locate the button via:

- XPath
- ID
- Name

The Picture shows the HTML Code of the Modal.
[Browser Source Code of the Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNZvj.png)

The Code in the Screenshot:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-header">
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title" id="cd8fac22-96a4-4ce5-a185-dcee905e2c7b_title">Löschen</div>
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-close-button" style="display: none;"><button class="close"
                    aria-label="close">×</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-body">
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-message">Wollen Sie diesen Eintrag wirklich löschen ?</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="display: block;"><button class="btn btn-secondary bootstrap4-dialog-button"
            id="2e70b9f9-288b-4081-b5e3-3476b3c16584">Abbruch</button><button
            class="btn btn-warning bootstrap4-dialog-button" id="9c4317a1-14bf-47e4-b789-078325377193">Löschen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Button I am not able to locate is the very last element
`class="btn btn-warning bootstrap4-dialog-button" id="9c4317a1-14bf-47e4-b789-078325377193">Löschen</button>`

Thank you for your time.

PS: First time posting here ever and new to software development, so please be gentle :D

I tried to locate a button on a modal.
Selenium is not able to locate the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `ID=00d43143-fd7b-4e93-89a2-c48370d9a875`, this value is dynamic. i.e. value changes each time the page gets loaded.

Why don't you construct an XPATH expression as below,

To locate <kbd>Abbruch</kbd>:

```
//button[text()='Abbruch']
```

To locate <kbd>Löschen</kbd>:

```
//button[text()='Löschen']
```

Comment: It should be `By.XPath` not `By.Id`

Comment: Yes i realised it... trying it out

Comment: For clarity this was my comment before but i deleted it because i realised that i forgot the change by.Xpath:

You were right the ID changes when reloading the page. I didn´t know that. And I changed the Xpath to `IWebElement DeleteButton = DeleteModalPopUpFooter.FindElement(By.Id("//button[text()='Löschen']"));` as you recommended but I get the same error: "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#\/\/button\[text\(\)\=\'Löschen\'\]"}

Comment: Try to wait before performing the action. Use this `Thread.Sleep(10000);` before locating the Delete button.

Comment: Changing from `(By.Id("00d43143-fd7b-4e93-89a2-c48370d9a875"));`
to the XPath `(By.XPath("//button[text()='Löschen']"))` is the solution. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: I had the problem that the modal doesn´t close after i click the delete button but with the  added `Thread.Sleep(10000);` it closes

Answer (score 0):

as @Shawn mentioned, value of your element ID (example: 00d43143-fd7b-4e93-89a2-c48370d9a875 ) is most probably changing.
What is hindering to choose the working XPath method ? You can get XPath of the button without ID as well, something like:

```
By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/button[text()='Löschen']")
```

or

```
By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
```

I didnt test, just experiment yourself.